# Jupyter notebook cannot add new cells

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have installed jupyter notebook in my ubuntu 20.04 device.
These are the versions of the installed libraries:

```
jupyter core     : 4.6.3
jupyter-notebook : 6.1.4
qtconsole        : 4.7.7
ipython          : 7.19.0
ipykernel        : 5.3.4
jupyter client   : 6.1.7
jupyter lab      : 2.2.6
nbconvert        : 6.0.7
ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
nbformat         : 5.0.8
traitlets        : 5.0.5
```

When I open notebook in the browser I cannot add cells in the notebook because there are no buttons and menus to do so.

When I open a file in the notebook this is what I get. [image]

I have tried reinstalling the libraries and repeating the process , but I cannot fix the issue.

Comment: do you need to work with Jupyter stand alone version? otherwise I recommend you anaconda, i use it on ubuntu 20.04 with no issues whatsoever

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using conda helped. I spent hours trying to fix it. Do you know why it does not work jupyter installed from pip.

Comment: no, I don't know, sorry, I remember having similar issues  and everything was sorted when I used conda.,